# Как адаптировать итеративный алгоритм обхода бинарного дерева к обходу сильноветвящегося дерева?

Tags: алгоритм, дерево

Мне необходимо реализовать итеративный обход сильноветвящегося дерева в глубину, в порядке "вершина – левое поддерево – правое поддерево". Как сделать это для бинарного дерева, используя стек, понятно, но как сделать для сильноветвящегося не очень ясно. Прошу ссылку на литературу или на реализацию на любом языке.

Пример итеративного обхода на языке C#:

```
var stack = new Stack<Node<int>>();
var top = root;

while (top != null || stack.Count != 0)
{
    if (stack.Count != 0)
    {
        top = stack.Pop();
    }

    while (top != null)
    {
        if (top.Right != null)
        {
            stack.Push(top.Right);
        }

        var value = top.Value; // Обработка значения.

        top = top.Left;
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чем разница? Этот термин впервые слышу от вас. Можете сказать разницу?

Comment: Если каждый узел дерева это вектор ссылок на поддеревья, то заносите в стек индекс ссылки на следующее поддерево. Как только дошли до конца вектора, возвращайтесь из стека

Comment: Если вы понимаете что делать для двоичного дерева, то тоже самое надо сделать для любого другого дерева. Только в случае двоичного дерева вы делаете "это" два раза, а для любого дерева надо сделать "это" несколько раз. Проще объяснить, если в вопросе есть пример итеративного обхода для двоичного дерева.

Comment: @avp, недавно узнал способ без индекса)

Comment: @Stanislav Volodarskiy, пример алгоритма для обхода бинарного дерева добавил.

Comment: И стоит пояснить, что такое сильноветвящееся дерево и как оно у вас устроено.

Comment: Как я понимаю, сильноветвящееся дерево это такое дерево, у узлов которого больше чем два потомка. Термина лучше я не нашел, но в Сети используется именно такая терминология. Т.о. мне нужно просто адаптировать алгоритм итеративного обхода бинарного дерева в глубину на случай N потомков у узла. Устроено оно у меня очень просто - в каждом узле находится массив потомков (в примере два поля - Left и Right, но пример дан для бинарного дерева). Дерево не упорядоченно, не сбалансированно, это просто рекурсивная структура данных, чем-то напоминающая дерево каталогов в ФС. И ее нужно обойти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Аналогичный код для дерева с неограниченным числом детей в узле:

```
var stack = new Stack<Node<int>>();
var top = root;

while (top != null || stack.Count != 0)
{
    if (stack.Count != 0)
    {
        top = stack.Pop();
    }

    while (top != null)
    {
        for (var i = top.Children.Length - 1; i > 0; --i)
        {
            stack.Push(top.Children[i]);
        }

        var value = top.Value; // Обработка значения.

        top = top.Children[0];
    }
}
```

Ваш код не самый простой: два цикла, видимо сделана оптимизация для левых ветвей. Всё можно сделать проще:

```
var stack = new Stack<Node<int>>();

stack.Push(root);
while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    var top = stack.Pop();
    if (top != null)
    {
        var value = top.Value; // Обработка значения.
        stack.Push(top.Right);
        stack.Push(top.Left);
    }
}
```

Аналог для массива детей:

```
var stack = new Stack<Node<int>>();

stack.Push(root);
while (stack.Count > 0)
{
    var top = stack.Pop();
    if (top != null)
    {
        var value = top.Value; // Обработка значения.
        for (var i = top.Children.Length - 1; i >= 0; --i)
        {
            stack.Push(top.Children[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Хотелось бы уточнить, что должно быть вместо "top = top.Left;" в первом варианте реализации. Какой-то i-й элемент из массива Children? Мне кажется, или мы где-то должны хранить индекс просматриваемого потомка для текущего уровня вложенности?

Comment: Я забыл поправить. Там нулевой индекс.

Comment: Возможен вариант, когда вы храните в стеке узел и индекс. При извлечении узла индекс увеличивается на единицу и помещается в стек (пока индекс внутри массива). Но проще этого не делать.

Answer (score 2):

Рекурсивно:

```
function go(v) {
  handle(v)

  for (var x of v.children) {
    go(x)
  }
}
```

Нерекурсивно:

```
function go(v) {
  var st = [v]

  while (st.length) {
    var x = st.pop()

    handle(x)

    for (var q=x.children.length; --q!==-1; ) {
      st.push(x.children[q])
    }
  }
}
```